# What spacecraft technologies are subject to international standards?

Tags: standards

I'm asking about standards promoted by ISO, IEEE, ITU, intergovernmental bodies, or simply de-facto standards.

For instance, [MIL-STD-1553](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIL-STD-1553) defines serial data bus used in avionics all over the world.

What are the significant technologies applicable to spacecraft where international standardization has taken root? (The above example of 1553 buses also shows extensive use of the standard in decidedly non-NATO countries - e.g. Russia, are there any other standardization "success stories"?).

What are the specific disadvantages of international standardization in space exploration?

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to be very broad. 
Different countries employ different types of Qualification Standards. Here are a few
NASA Technical Standards Program, Europe - ECSS (European Cooperation for Space Standardisation), JAXA parts and Standards Program etc.

Based on your broad Criteria, I would like to quote an example for your understanding.
If there is a company that is delivering a Ground Segment to say European Space Agency, then the company should follow all the Qualification standards mentioned in the ECSS Ground Systems and Operations document.